# VBA: Removing an empty placeholder XML Ribbon Tab from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which had a custom `XML` ribbon. I removed all the code using the `Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office` and now I have an empty tab (no header and content) sitting in my ribbon. How can I get rid of that empty tab? I'm using Office 2016.

Here are some screenshots:

I removed the XML completely
[image]

Here's the tab I need removed
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may try to remove the tab manually. Change the workbook extension .xlsm to .zip, unzip the contents, open file `\customUI\customUI.xml`, remove unnecessary `<tab>` node, then zip the contents back and rename extension .zip to .xlsm.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! There was some other xml file that contained the empty tab. The strange thing was that this xml didn't appear in the Custom UI Editor. Please put it as an answer and I will mark it as correct. I can answer my own question and reference your comment but I would rather give you credit directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to remove the tab manually. Follow the steps:

1. Change the workbook extension .xlsm to .zip.
2. Unzip the contents.
3. Open file `\customUI\customUI.xml`.
4. Remove unnecessary `<tab>` node, save changes.
5. Zip the contents back.
6. Rename extension .zip to .xlsm.